# CSS internal links not relative to css file?

Tags: html, css, relative-path

I must be missing something, are css internal file links relative to the css file? searching and every source so far says yes but my file doesn't seem to want to load the fonts (fontawesome). The index.html file loads and displays the fonts corectly so i know it's working; however, the myfile.html page that loads the css relative doesn't work. In order for the myfile.html to work i have to change the css file to load relative to the myfile.html page (or so it seems) so `../fonts/` but then that breaks the index.html page.

Because of the way things are hosted and done i have to keep eveything relative or i would just use `/fonts/` but that's not an option at the moment.

Also to keep it shorter I'm just listing the parts of fontawesome needed for the example listed

probably missing something simple but all the reference i pull up says it should load relative to the .css file.

here is the folder/file structure

```
- home
    - inc
            myfile.html
    - fontawesome
            fontawesome.min.css
            - fonts
    index.html
```

---- index.html ----

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="fontawesome/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div><i class="fas fa-bars"></i> fun stuff here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---- myfile.html ----

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="../fontawesome/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>myfile</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div><i class="fas fa-bars"></i> fun stuff here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---- fontawesome.min.css ----

```
.fa,.fab,.fal,.far,.fas{
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    display:inline-block;
    font-style:normal;
    font-variant:normal;
    text-rendering:auto;
    line-height:1
}
.fas.fa-pull-left{
    margin-right:.3em
}
.fa.fa-pull-right,.fab.fa-pull-right,.fal.fa-pull-right,.far.fa-pull-right,.fas.fa-pull-right{
    margin-left:.3em
}

@font-face{
    font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:400;
    src:url(fonts/fa-regular-400.eot);
    src:url(fonts/fa-regular-400.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),
            url(fonts/fa-regular-400.woff2) format("woff2"),
            url(fonts/fa-regular-400.woff) format("woff"),
            url(fonts/fa-regular-400.ttf) format("truetype"),
            url(fonts/fa-regular-400.svg#fontawesome) format("svg")
}
@font-face{
    font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:900;
    src:url(fonts/fa-solid-900.eot);
    src:url(fonts/fa-solid-900.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),
            url(fonts/fa-solid-900.woff2) format("woff2"),
            url(fonts/fa-solid-900.woff) format("woff"),
            url(fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf) format("truetype"),
            url(fonts/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome) format("svg")}

.fa,.far,.fas{
    font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Free"
}
.fa,.fas{
    font-weight:900
}
```

Comment: Use devtools (network) in browser and check where every request is going.

Comment: It appears to be a firefox problem(?), chrome and IE are working fine. I loaded it with the devtools and the network is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just shooting from the hip at this point. :-) Try editing the paths in your fontawesome.min.css. Just add ../ to each URL like so:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:400;
    src:url(../fonts/fa-regular-400.eot);
    src:url(../fonts/fa-regular-400.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),
            url(../fonts/fa-regular-400.woff2) format("woff2"),
            url(../fonts/fa-regular-400.woff) format("woff"),
            url(../fonts/fa-regular-400.ttf) format("truetype"),
            url(../fonts/fa-regular-400.svg#fontawesome) format("svg")
}
@font-face{
    font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:900;
    src:url(../fonts/fa-solid-900.eot);
    src:url(../fonts/fa-solid-900.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),
            url(../fonts/fa-solid-900.woff2) format("woff2"),
            url(../fonts/fa-solid-900.woff) format("woff"),
            url(../fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf) format("truetype"),
            url(../fonts/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome) format("svg")}
```

Comment: It's loading the fontawesome in both cases above, the problem is with the font itself being loaded inside the CSS. it doesn't appear to be relative to the CSS file like it should be. Double dots '../' means previous directory so '../fontawesome/fontawesome.min.css' inside the 'inc' directory like above actually means '/home/fontawesome/fontawesome.min.css'...your link would actually look for '/home/home/fontawesome/fontawesome.min.css'...correct me please if i'm wrong :)

Comment: My mistake, I guess I misunderstood the question (and should have excluded the leading '..'). So, you're telling me that it is loading fontawesome.min.css, but failing to display the icons/fonts you want to use?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page in question?

Comment: yes, for the page inside the 'inc' folder. the main index page is working fine with font, it's just when I load fontawesome through a relative link inside a sub directory. For the moment it's hosted on a local server :(

Comment: So, if you move myfile.html up to the home/ directory does it load the fonts as expected? If so, I'm guessing that it is not loading fontawesome.min.css from the subdirectory.

Comment: yes, and it does load fontawesome from the inc directory as it formats the block correctly, it's just the fonts inside the CSS that don't want to load.

Comment: When you say 'the fonts inside the CSS' are you referring to the fonts inside fontawesome.min.css? Also, what is meant by 'it formats the block correctly'?

Comment: sorry, i'm not sure how to explain this better. yes the "@font-face" inside the fontawesome.min.css is not loading the fonts relative to the css file itself but it is loading the css file because the blocks that use fontawesome are being formatted according to the properties set by that css file. so it's applying the correct margins, inline-block display, line-height, etc. It is the actual fonts defined inside the css file that aren't being loaded. It would appear that fonts aren't loaded relative to the css file calling them as would be expected based on docs and examples found.

Comment: Try adding this to your .htaccess file:<IfModule mod_headers.c> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" </IfModule>

Comment: it's not an apache server :(. but everything is hosted on the server so that wouldn't help the problem I would imagine.

Comment: @Viking NM I've edited my answer above. Humor me and see if that works.

Comment: it still isn't working, narrowed it down to a firefox problem

Comment: It does appear to be a Firefox bug related to their stricter same-origin policy. You can relax this by setting security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy to false in about:config, but as this gives the page access to your entire local filesystem, it's something to be used with caution. It should be noted that the problem seems to disappear when uploaded to a server.